# How to load data to google colaboratory for others to use without downloading the data folders?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I use the 'mount drive' to use the dataset folder.

However, the google drive belongs to only me so others who want to run my code on colab have to download the dataset and upload to their google drive, then mount drive to run the code.

Is there any solution for others to run my the code without downloading the dataset?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I made a library to do just that

```
!pip install kora
from kora import drive
drive.download_folder(folder_id)
```

Comment: folder_id means drive link, doesn't it

Comment: It's just the ID, inside the link: `1HvIeNhqtFVllXFWzH5NawDdnIfgGDwCK`